# Mocking a generic method properly

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

New to Moq and Mocking in general. Testing a class that has a generic RepositoryFactory and uses several of it's repositories. Should I initialize like this or is there some better way?

```
Mock<IRepositoryFactory> factory;
        Mock<IRepository<User>> userRepository;
        Mock<IRepository<Role>> roleRepository;
        Mock<IRepository<Meeting>> meetingRepository;

        [TestInitialize()]
        public void MyTestInitialize()
        {
            meetingRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Meeting>>();
            //some meeting setup

            userRepository = new Mock<IRepository<User>>();
            //some user setup

            roleRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Role>>();
            //some role setup

            factory = new Mock<IRepositoryFactory>();
            factory.Setup(f => f.CreateRepository<Meeting>()).Returns(meetingRepository.Object);
            factory.Setup(f => f.CreateRepository<User>()).Returns(userRepository.Object);
            factory.Setup(f => f.CreateRepository<Role>()).Returns(roleRepository.Object);
```

Note that I could have mcuh more.

here I'm doing it all in my initialize method but guess I should do it individually or something also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to set up `f => f.CreateRepository<T>()`, considering that your repository setup could be different for each `T`.  Aside from that, you can use functional specifications (see this [blog post](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/old-style-imperative-mocks-vs-moq-functional-specifications/)), which makes things a bit cleaner.

For your example, it would look like this:

```
var factory = Mock.Of<IRepositoryFactory>(
    x => 
    x.CreateRepository<Meeting>() == Mock.Of<IRepository<Meeting>>() &&
    x.CreateRepository<Role>() == Mock.Of<IRepository<Role>>() &&
    x.CreateRepository<User>() == Mock.Of<IRepository<User>>()
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, I don't see a problem with your code.

However, it's a bit worrisome that you haven't even started to work on the class you want to test, and already have 4 mocks, and "could have much more". It sounds like an awful lot of setup.

On top of that, if my understanding of [TestInitialize] is correct, it means that for every test in this class, every repository will be setup the same way. That's probably going to get in the way of specifying tests with different conditions.

Maybe you should consider avoiding [TestInitialize], and setup the repositories you need in each test method, specific to what you want to assert - and progressively extract the setup for each repository into shared methods, following a BDD-style : "Given_User_Of_Type_VIP()" returns a Repository with a user of type VIP setup.

Comment: Well the reason I could have much more is that this is a WCF service class that implements a few servicecontracts and I'm currently not using TDD. The service only has a RepositoryFactory class but I have to mock the repositories it might return.